# How can legend entries be obtained from different plots in a groupplot?

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I would like to place a legend outside an axis using symbols from multiple plots within a `groupplot`.  Trying it the way I show below doesn't seem to work, just the last entry is shown.  How can this be done in a way such that all entries are shown?

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={
        {group size=2 by 2}},
      legend to name=grouplegend]

      \nextgroupplot[title=One]
      \addplot+[color=Blue] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
      \addlegendentry{A}

      \nextgroupplot[title=Two]
      \addplot+[color=Red] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
      \addlegendentry{B}

      \nextgroupplot[title=Three]
      \addplot+[color=Gray] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
      \addlegendentry{C}

      \nextgroupplot[title=Four]
      \addplot+[color=Orange] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
      \addlegendentry{D}

    \end{groupplot}

    \node (l1) at ($(group c1r2.south)!0.5!(group c2r2.south)$)
      [below, yshift=-2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/every axis title shift}]
      {\ref{grouplegend}};

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: four plots in a 2x2 grid showing the legend with only the last entry]

Comment: I think you're best off posting a feature request for this on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=224188&atid=1060659). PGFplots is being very actively developed, so there's a good chance of this being implemented relatively fast.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `/pgfplots/legend to name={<name>}` feature described in the manual reference under "Legends outside of an axis". The example quoted is:

```
% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
\pgfplotsset{footnotesize,samples=10}
\begin{center}% note that \centering uses less vspace...
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend columns=-1,
legend entries={$(x+0)^k$;,$(x+1)^k$;,$(x+2)^k$;,$(x+3)^k$},
legend to name=named,
title={$k=1$}]
\addplot {x};
\addplot {x+1};
\addplot {x+2};
\addplot {x+3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={$k=2$}]
\addplot {x^2};
\addplot {(x+1)^2};
\addplot {(x+2)^2};
\addplot {(x+3)^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={$k=3$}]
\addplot {x^3};
\addplot {(x+1)^3};
\addplot {(x+2)^3};
\addplot {(x+3)^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\ref{named}
\end{center}
```

Which produces:

[image: one legend to rule them all]

Edit: I guess this doesn't work for group plots. Here's a horrible hack that kinda works:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={
        {group size=2 by 2}},
        xmin=0,
        enlarge x limits=true,
      ]

      \nextgroupplot[title=One, legend to name=grouplegend]
      \addplot+[color=Blue] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
      \addlegendentry{A}
      \addplot+[color=Red] coordinates {(-1,0)};
      \addlegendentry{B}
      \addplot+[color=Gray] coordinates {(-1,0)};
      \addlegendentry{C}
      \addplot+[color=Orange] coordinates {(-1,0)};
      \addlegendentry{D}

      \nextgroupplot[title=Two]
      \addplot+[color=Red] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};

      \nextgroupplot[title=Three]
      \addplot+[color=Gray] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};

      \nextgroupplot[title=Four]
      \addplot+[color=Orange] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};

    \end{groupplot}

    \node (l1) at ($(group c1r2.south)!0.5!(group c2r2.south)$)
      [below, yshift=-2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/every axis title shift}]
      {\ref{grouplegend}};

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: yay for hacks]

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this won't work for this case: You can't "collect" plots from different axes using this method. In the question, each axis contains one plot, but the legend should contain four entries (blue, red, gray and orange).

Comment: Ah, I see, d'oh. I've edited the answer with an idea to rectify the situation.

Comment: @Jake is correct.  I will look at the edit to see if it works.

Comment: FYI, I've just given the original answer a go and it does work now. I define legend to name=named in the group style=[]. After I \end{groupplot} \end{tikpicture}, I leave \ref{named} (before the \caption{}) and it aligns correctly.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else comes across this, in the current version of pgfplots (1.15) and using groupplot, slurms' & Carlisle's answer does indeed work. An example within a figure (edit: now including the document preamble and wrapper for compiling):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz} % To generate the plot from csv
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

% Standard presentation for graphs
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} % Allows to place the legend below plot



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={
            group size=2 by 2,
            xticklabels at=edge bottom,
            yticklabels at=edge left
        }, 
        height=0.4\textwidth,
        width=0.5\textwidth,
        xmin=-5, xmax=55,
        ymin=70, ymax=105,
        xtick={0,10,30,50},
        ytick={70,80,90,100},
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        legend to name=named,
        legend columns=-1
    ]

    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,98.65)(10,97.34)(30,91.23)(50,87.55)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,98.15)(10,96.34)(30,90.23)(50,83.55)};

    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,98.65)(10,97.34)(30,91.23)(50,87.55)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,98.15)(10,96.34)(30,90.23)(50,83.55)};    

    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,98.65)(10,97.34)(30,91.23)(50,87.55)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,98.15)(10,96.34)(30,90.23)(50,83.55)};    

    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,98.65)(10,97.34)(30,91.23)(50,87.55)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,98.15)(10,96.34)(30,90.23)(50,83.55)};


    \legend{Line 1, Line 2}

    \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \ref{named}

    \caption{My first groupplot plot.}


  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Provides the following in-document:

[image]

Comment: Could you add compileable code?

Comment: @Bobyandbob I can indeed -- I've added extra bits and checked it in Overleaf and it compiles :)

Comment: Thank you, thats helpfull for all!