# Common legend for groupplots involving plots generated by forloop

Tags: pgfplots, legend, groupplots

I'm trying to adapt the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192424/pgfplots-single-legend-in-a-group-plot?noredirect=1&lq=1) ([this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58719/how-can-legend-entries-be-obtained-from-different-plots-in-a-groupplot) is also relevant) where legend entries can be added via a loop. For instance if we  have a collection of N curves depending on more than one parameter it is nice to compare each collection within a groupplot environment. The following adaptation

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\getLab}[1]{plot_#1}
\newcommand{\getLeg}[1]{curve #1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[cycle list name=color list,
        group style={group name=myplot, group size= 2 by 2}] 


        \nextgroupplot[ylabel=throughput, 
                every axis y label/.append style={at=(ticklabel cs:0)}] % Common y label 
        %\addlegendimage{empty legend}
        %\addlegendentryexpanded{param 1} % very convenient
        \foreach \n in {1,...,3} {
            \addplot {x^(\n)};  
            \label{\getLab{\n}}
        }

        \nextgroupplot
        \foreach \n in {1,...,3} {
            \addplot {x^(\n + 1)};  
        }
        \nextgroupplot
        \foreach \n in {1,...,3} {
            \addplot {x^(\n + 2)};  
        }
        \nextgroupplot
        \foreach \n in {1,...,3} {
            \addplot {x^(\n + 3)};  
        }

\end{groupplot}

\path (myplot c1r1.north west|-current bounding box.north)--
      coordinate(legendpos)
      (myplot c2r1.north east|-current bounding box.north);
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=south,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.2em,
    draw
  ] at ([yshift=1ex] legendpos) {
    % Problem starts:
    %\foreach \m in {1,...,3} { % ?? this just looks silly
    %    \ref{\getLab{\m}} & \getLeg{\m} &
    %}
    %
    % This compiles surprisingly
    %\foreach \m in {1,...,3} { \ref{\getLab{\m}} } & 
    %\foreach \m in {1,...,3} { \ref{\getLeg{\m}} } &

    % Working
    \ref{plot_2} & curve 2 &
    \ref{plot_2} & curve 2 &
    \ref{plot_3} & curve 3
\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

which is what I want in the end, but would like to 'functionally' generate the matrix structure used at the end similar to the way the labels were generated. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\foreach` creates a TeX group around the loop code, which prevents the Ti*k*Z matrix from considering the `&`s as column delimiters. In order to solve this, you can generate the code using an `expl3` function such as `\int_step_inline:nnnn`, which does not create a group around the user code.

Note: Ti*k*Z matrices expect the column delimiter `&` with category code 13 (active). This is *not* the standard category code for `&`, which is 4 (alignment tab). That is why my definition of `\myAddLegendEntries` uses `\pgfmatrixnextcell` instead of `&` (at the place where `\myAddLegendEntries` is defined, `&` has its standard category code 4, which wouldn't work as expected when inserted inside the Ti*k*Z matrix).

The delimiter between entries is the optional argument of `\myAddLegendEntries`. It defaults to `\pgfmatrixnextcell`, but you might want to change it in order to modify the appearance of the legend. For instance, you could add things before or after the `\pgfmatrixnextcell`, or you could use this to obtain a multiline legend:

```latex
\myAddLegendEntries[\\]{1}{1}{3} % initial value, step, final value
  {\ref{\getLab{#1}} & \getLeg{#1}}
```

[image]

Full code with a single-line legend, as in the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__algae_legend_entries_seq

% Arguments: separator, initial, step, final
\NewDocumentCommand \myAddLegendEntries { O{\pgfmatrixnextcell} m m m m }
 {
   \seq_clear:N \l__algae_legend_entries_seq
   \int_step_inline:nnnn {#2} {#3} {#4}
     { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__algae_legend_entries_seq {#5} }
   \seq_use:Nn \l__algae_legend_entries_seq {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\getLab}[1]{plot_#1}
\newcommand{\getLeg}[1]{curve #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[cycle list name=color list,
    group style={group name=myplot, group size= 2 by 2}]
    \nextgroupplot[
      % Common y label
      ylabel=throughput,
      every axis y label/.append style={at=(ticklabel cs:0)}]
    \foreach \n in {1,...,3} {
        \addplot {x^(\n)};
        \label{\getLab{\n}}
    }
    \nextgroupplot
    \foreach \n in {1,...,3} {
        \addplot {x^(\n + 1)};
    }
    \nextgroupplot
    \foreach \n in {1,...,3} {
        \addplot {x^(\n + 2)};
    }
    \nextgroupplot
    \foreach \n in {1,...,3} {
        \addplot {x^(\n + 3)};
    }
\end{groupplot}

\path (myplot c1r1.north west|-current bounding box.north)--
      coordinate(legendpos)
      (myplot c2r1.north east|-current bounding box.north);

\matrix[matrix of nodes, anchor=south, draw, inner sep=0.2em]
  at ([yshift=1ex] legendpos)
  {
    \myAddLegendEntries{1}{1}{3} % initial value, step, final value
      {\ref{\getLab{#1}} & \getLeg{#1}}
    \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]